# Which sentence is the correct one?

Tags: grammar

> My friend: You can't just come in and take credit. 
> Me: But I did just
> come in and took credit.

(Referring to how i had just then taken credit for something.)

My friend said that I should have said,

> But I did just come in and take credit.

Help settle our difference of opinion? :)

Answer (score 1):

Simplify it and you will see that your friend is correct.

> You can't X.

> I did X.

In this case, X is "just come in and take credit". So "did" handles the conjugation of both "come" and "take"

Answer (score -2):

"But I did just come in and I took credit" is grammatically correct. "But I did just come in and I did take credit" also is grammatically correct. So the question is what "But I did just come in and [took/take] credit" is short for. If you what the emphasizing "did" to apply to both verbs, then it should be "take". This option sounds the most natural to me, but the other one is not, strictly speaking, incorrect.

Comment: The *did* applies to both verbs whether you want it to or not.